# Neater way of checking adding/removing a CSS class using 'hasClass' in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Overview

From time to time in jQuery I want to check a condition of some kind, and then based on the result add/remove a cssClass to an element.

Before calling add(remove)Class, I always check to see if that class isn't (or is) applied already.

### In code, this translates to

```
var myElement = $('#something'),
    someClass = 'coolClass';

if (someCondition) {

   // addClass, but only if that class isn't already on this element
   if (!myElement.hasClass(someClass)) { myElement.addClass(someClass); }

} else {

   // otherwise, removeClass, but only if it's already on this element
   if (myElement.hasClass(someClass)) { myElement.removeClass(someClass); }

}
```

### Is there a neater way of writing the above?

I'm sure there must be a nicer way of doing this, as the nested if statements smell to me.

### Clarity on toggling

Just a clarifying note (added after the answers below). It is important to note here than `toggleClass(className)` will not suffice as I *explicitally* want to remove or add based on a condition check - and need to account for the 'toggle' going out of sync. (Adam gives an example in a comment on Rob's answer below).

Comment: The same thing without jQuery: [Add or remove a class based on a condition](/q/69641793/4642212).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var myElement = $('#something'),
someClass = 'coolClass';
myElement.toggleClass(someClass, someCondition);
```

`toggleClass` does your check for you essentially.  If you do a `toggleClass('class', true)` it'll only actually put that class on there if it's not already, and will never add more than one class of the same name.

Comment: @Adam - perfect, I was obviously aware of `toggleClass` but never knew of the `switch` argument added in 1.3. I didn't want a simple toggle as (as pritaeas says) the condition is the thing I'm getting at here

Comment: @beardtwizzle Great!  Glad I was able to answer your question for you!

Comment: @AdamTerlson when I used this, I found that `addClass` or `removeClass` was still being called every time `toggleClass` was called.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method, which removes a class if it exists, and adds it if it does not.

```
var myElement = $('#something'),
    someClass = 'coolClass';

myElement.toggleClass(someClass, someCondition);
```

Reviewing your current code, I add that there's no need to use `hasClass`. jQuery automatically deals correctly with the request: A class name is only added once, so using `$("<a>").addClass("xxx").addClass("xxx").attr("class")` will return `x`, instead of `xxx xxx`.

Comment: Bah!  You beat me by 16 seconds. :(  However, you forgot `condition`.

Comment: @AdamTerlson: You don't need a condition, the OP just wants to toggle the classname from the element.

Comment: @Purmou Sounded to me like he wanted to toggle something based on a condition.  `If (condition) addClass, Else removeClass`.  That's toggling based on a condition, not just a toggle.  Consider calling his code twice with condition being true each time.  That'll leave the classes unchanged.  In RobW's code, it'll be removed on the second call.

Comment: @Rob W - Yes Adam is right, I apologies for this not being made clearer in the question - I will amend accordingly

Answer (score 2):

.addClass() will only add a class if it doesn't already exist and .removeClass() only removes an existing class so the following should work:

```
if (someCondition) {
  myElement.addClass(someClass);
} else {
  myElement.removeClass(someClass);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery 1.4 there is a neater way of doing this using `toggleClass` function. See details [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

this should do it as well

```
if (someCondition) {
    $(myElement+":not(.someClass)").addClass(someClass);
}else{
    $(myElement+":has(.someClass)").removeClass(someClass);
}
```